Best way to rsync as root
I'm not a friend of sudo or password bypass tools, so my idea is to allow root/su login only on a local machine by a defined user.
Is it possible to tunnel rsync passthrough to root, or is it a bad idea?

I need on my remote machine two SSH keys, first to login as user, then for a second SSH to login as root to backup the system


This seems more like an XY Problem - the whole point of sudo is so root doesn't have to be used as a login user; excluding NAS OSes like TrueNAS and single-user OSes [those found on routers and IoT/embedded devices], root should never be used as a login user due to the security implications of doing so (same as System should never be used as a login user on Windows). Some OSes [aforementioned] are intended to have root be the login user, whereas most OSes are not, hence sudo (setting up sudo for a user is straightforward)

Okay, in my case i use a Root Server without root login.. but its not a  Multiuser enviroment, only Single-User to configure Backups and run System backups.

sudo has restrictions on what the user does and doesn't have access to via what's configured in sudoers when configuring sudo for the user. For SSH, it's highly unlikely the SSH key would be compromised (assuming ed25519 or rsa2048), although it should always be encrypted with a secure passphrase during generation, thereby preventing use if the key itself is gained access to (this also allows safely storing it on a smartphone like Android, where /sdcard is rw by any app). IMHO, login by root should always be disabled, and SSH should only be allowed via a key, not a passphrase.

Is the Root Server OS intended by the OS developer to have root be the login user (e.g. what OS is installed)? A single-user OS is a very specific type of OS - it doesn't mean there's not other users, there are, but root is the only login user by design and other login users aren't meant to be configured - e.g. all router firmwares are single-user OSes, whereas almost all full OSes are not. Some full OSes, like TrueNAS (likely other server OSes as well), are intended for root to be the primary local login user for OS management
